# Heroku migration: PG::Error: ERROR: relation "roles" does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, migration

When I run the command `heroku run rake db:migrate` for deploy my app to Heroku, I get this error:

```
PG::Error: ERROR:  relation "roles" does not exist
:             SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod), d.adsrc, a.attnotnull
              FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
                ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
             WHERE a.attrelid = '"roles"'::regclass
               AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
             ORDER BY a.attnum

Tasks: TOP => db:reset => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Also I have tried `heroku run rake db:reset` or `heroku restart`, but didn't help me.

The RoR & PostgreSQL version I used in the app is

```
gem 'rails', '3.2.1'
gem 'pg', '~> 0.13.2'
```

On localhost is working everything well, but because of this error I can migrate my database to Heroku.

Could anyone give me please some advice, how to solve this problem?

Thank you so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

rails rake commands are restricted on Heroku. You can use 'heroku pg' to manipulate the db. 'heroku pg help' to see all available commands.

Try

```
heroku pg:reset SHARED_DATABASE
```

Then: heroku run rake db:migrate

Then restart: heroku restart

Comment: I just tried what you advised me, but still the same error... `heroku pg:reset SHARED_DATABASE` unfortunately didn't help

Comment: Did your database used to work and now it doesn't? Or has it not worked from the very beginning?

Comment: Did you get the above error on the pg:reset command? Or did pg:reset work successfully and you got the same error on db:migrate?

Comment: the database on Heroku doesn't work. `heroku pg:reset SHARED_DATABASE` was executed successfully. Then when I ran `heroku run rake migrate`, I got again the same error.

Comment: It sounds like there's a problem with the migrations you are trying to run. Probably the order in which they are being called. Can you post the text of your migrations?

Comment: do you the trace output? (I am not sure what do you mean)

Comment: I'm talking about the files in db/migrate. I wonder about them because the error says that the relation 'roles' is missing. If you have a file in db/migrate that creates a roles model, can you post that?